# Django-admin forgot password

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

login.html

```
   {% url 'password_reset' as password_reset_url %}
  <div class="password-reset-link">
    <a href="{{ password_reset_url }}">{% trans 'Şifremi Unuttum ?' %}</a>
  </div>
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'Web'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),

    ]
```

as you can see pasword_reset_url included but i'm not able to see this href in my login page how can i configure  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your `urls.py` you don't have an `admin_reset_password`. So just write:

```
{% url 'password_reset' as password_reset_url %}
```

Comment: thanks now i'm able to see link but url its not going to register/password_reset_form.html. Link just refreshing login page

Comment: editted html file but as i said link not going to password_reset_form

Comment: This question is answered, ask another if it's not working, so we don't go too far from the original question. If you have another problem after this new one, we're not going to do it all in this answer :).
And you need to add other details : what is the url, can you access password_reset by typing the url directly in your browser?